How to use NOTIFY / LISTEN Postgres mechanism or sqlalchemy events with async sqlalchemy (2.x style)?
I'm looking for a way to use NOTIFY / LISTEN Postgres mechanism or sqlalchemy.event with sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.get_history asynchronously using async/await syntax. I didn't find the usage documentation on https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/event.html and https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html.
I've found a good example of what I need here, but there is synchronous code only.
I would really appreciate any help

How does the Postgres notify/listen mechanism relate to this?  It is not intrinsically related to SQLA events.  And please ensure that your question is understandable without having to access external resources like blog posts.

If you want to track ORM attributes, you'll need to use ORM events

Thanks for the note, I changed the question a little bit. ORM events are also suitable for my task, as well as the notify/listen mechanism. I'm looking for a way to use any of it asynchronously
